# Why $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] not working when page refreshed every 2 secs in Chrome?

Tags: php, ajax

I am using PHP & ajax. And I am getting hashe from url of the page in every 2 seconds using following code. It works perfectly on all browsers except chrome.

In Chrome, it fetches hash from URL every 2 seconds, after maybe 5 seconds it stopped getting what it used to get

```
$destination_hashed = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], -32, 32);
```

Following are ajax script which I have used

```
$(document).ready( function() {

     var interval = setInterval( function() {
             $.ajax ({
                     url: "users.php",
                     success: function(data) {
                             $("#users").html(data);
                     }
             });
     }, 2000);
});
```

Comment: Note related to the question at all, but please note that the HTTP referrer comes from the user and may be manipulated or not sent, so it should be treated as any other user input.